# BASH: Getting the md5 hash of file on remote server

Tags: bash, shell-script, hashsum

Is there a way I could get the md5 hash of a file on a remote server?

I'm looking for a command like

```
md5 hlin117@server:/path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no remote md5.

The closest you can get is to execute the command on the remote server:

```
ssh hlin117@server md5sum /path/to/file.txt
```

Obviously, `md5sum` must be installed on the remote server.

Alternatively, get the file and do it locally:

```
scp hlin117@server:/path/to/file.txt .
md5sum file.txt
rm file.txt
```

Or, as @Cyrus pointed out:

```
ssh hlin117@server cat /path/to/file.txt | md5sum
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first solution worked. (PS: I wanted to get the md5 hash sum so I don't need to scp it locally.)

Comment: With a local md5sum: `ssh hlin117@server cat /path/to/file.txt | md5sum`